How can a div content be crushed by another div content by using CSS?
In the below HTML Code (I simulated my original code by my question),
"helloworld" text is top of the "helloworld2" text

I am trying to "helloworld" is next to "helloworld2" like this :

Friendly reminder, Each text (helloworld,2,3) should inside their own div.

In addition to that, I don't want to use JS to fix this issue because of the code complexity increasing. I just want to fix it with CSS or HTML changing.
I tried z-index and display keywords and other structures to fix this issue but I couldn't fix it. How can I achieve it?


.container {
  margin: 0;
}

.leftSide {
  float: left;
  width: 85%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
}

.rightSide {
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: blue;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftSide">
    <div style="float:left; width:100%;  ">
      <h2>hello world</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div style="float:left; width:100%;  ">
        <h2 style="float:right">hello world2</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="float:left;  width:100%;  ">
        <h2>hello world3</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightSide">
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
  </div>
</div>




You can make these elements to occupy same line when they have e.g. 50% of width, so they will be displayed one after another.
But this will display "hello world 2" next to "hello world", not other way around. Maybe add top padding/margin if needed


.container {
  margin: 0;
}

.leftSide {
  float: left;
  width: 85%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
}

.rightSide {
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: blue;
}

[class*="col-"] {
   float: left;
}

.col-50 {
  width: 50%;
}

.col-100 {
  width: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftSide">
    <div class="col-50">
      <h2>hello world</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="col-50">
        <h2 style="float:right">hello world2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-100">
        <h2>hello world3</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightSide">
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
  </div>
</div>




Thank you for sharing, it is clean and contains only CSS editing, exactly what I was looking for :)

Experiment with flexes like:


.container {
  margin: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}
.leftSide {
  width: 85%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
}

.rightSide {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: blue;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="leftSide">
      <h2>hello world</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="rightSide">
      <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
      <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="leftSide">
      <h2>hello world</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="leftSide">
      <h2>hello world</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="leftSide">
      <h2>hello world</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




flex makes CSS so much easier, made me so happy when I started using it
